# Web RTC Video streaming not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, firefox, video-streaming

I am using one way broadcasting in Dot Net MVC web site for video streaming. I am using following example to complete the task https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/master/webrtc-broadcasting/index.html . Its working fine in Google chrome but not working in Mozilla Firefox and internet explorer also.

Can anyone please help me what i have to do make it working in Mozilla Firefox and internet explorer or please suggest me another way to broadcast in my website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be because of Mozilla's JavaScript engine. Chrome uses V8 engine which supports WebRTC completely as WebRTC even uses V8 Engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with configuration in configuration page( open about:config) for keys media.peerconnection.*
Like, media.peerconnection.enabled should be true(by default it is always true).
One setting which creates problem is media.peerconnection.ice.proxy_only. In case its value is true, you would not able to see video. So ensure it's value is false. i.e.
media.peerconnection.ice.proxy_only = false.

Hope it will help..